Scheme theoretic reduction map for elliptic curves
Consider $K$ a local field with $\text{char }k=0$ and $A$ an abelian surface over  $O_K$. Let $A[2]$ be the 2-torsion finite flat group scheme over $O_K$ and $A[2]^\circ$ be the connected component of $A[2]$ that contains the identity. There is a connected étale exact sequence
$$0\to A[2]^\circ\to A[2]\to A[2]^\text{ét}\to 0$$
where the last term is the largest étale group scheme quotient of $A[2]$ over $O_K$.
By Galois theory, $A[2]^\text{ét}(\bar{K})=A[2]^\text{ét}(\bar{K_\text{nr}})\cong A[2]^\text{ét}(\bar{k})=A[2](\bar{k})$ where $k$ is the residue field of $K$. Taking the $\bar{K}$-points of the above exact sequence gives
$$0\to A[2]^\circ(\bar{K})\to A[2](\bar{K})\to A[2](\bar{k})\to 0.$$
I wonder is there any explicit charaterization of $A[2](\bar{K})\to A[2](\bar{k})$. I recall in my elliptic curve course there exists a map $\rho:\mathbb{P}^2_{\mathbb{Q}_p}\to\mathbb{P}^2_{\mathbb{F}_p}$. Given $[x,y,z]\in\mathbb{P}^2_{\mathbb{Q}_p}$, we scale it so that the coordinates are in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and at least one of them is in $\mathbb{Z}_p^\times$.Then $\rho$ reduces $[x,y,z]$ to $\mathbb{F}_p$. I am not sure how to make this a map in scheme theoretic sense though.

Let $X$ be a proper scheme over a valuation ring $R$ (e.g. the completion of the ring of integers of an algebraic closure of a local field). If $K$ is the fraction field of $R$, then by the valuative criterion of properness, we have a map $X(K) \to X(R)$. Then we are free to reduce mod the maximal ideal of $R$ to get a map $X(R) \to X(k)$.
(Projective space is proper, and the scaling argument that you made is a valid proof of this fact once you know the valuative criterion. The uniqueness of the extension means that this "reduction map" plays well with embeddings, so once you have a concrete embedding into projective space, you can compute the coordinate-wise reduction, just as for elliptic curves.)
